# Вывод данных с MySql в select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Имеется форма в которой есть `<select>` (Код ниже).

```
<label>Все хорошо?</label>
<select name="status" class="status" required>
    <option disabled selected></option>
    <option value="Да">Да</option>
    <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
    <option value="Наверное">Наверное</option>
</select>
```

При заполнении таблицы и выбора нужного `<option>` все успешно загружается в БД.

Данные выводятся в таблицу последним полем которого есть кнопка "Редактировать запись" при нажатии на которую открывается форма в которой все поля заполняются из этого же поля. По сути быстрое редактирование с использованием Ajax

Теперь собственно проблема и вопрос:

1. Проблема в том, что я не могу реализовать вывод данных (при редактировании) в `<select>`, данные выводятся лишь в `<input>`. Т.е. если я при добавлении выбрал пункт меню "Да" то при редактировании это "Да" будет в обычном `<input>`
2. Вопрос в том, как мне правильно организовать вывод данных из БД (при редактировании) в `<select>`. Т.е что бы отображался ранее выбранный пункт меню "Да" с возможностью выбора другого пункта меню

Comment: Вам нужно ставить `selected` на тот `option`, который соответствует значению. Примерно так - `<option value="Да"<?= data['status']=='Да' ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Да</option>`

Comment: Что вам именно мешает написать `select` вместо `input`?